# Can someone explain how this Java code snippet works?

Tags: java, generics, collections

Here is the snippet (from Java Generics and Collections) and below is question:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Comparator<T> reverseOrder()
    {
        return new Comparator<T>() {
        public int compare(T o1, T o2) { return o2.compareTo(o1); }
    };
}
```

As I follow you have a method using a wildcard that extends comparable where it compares types T and "above." It then returns a new Comparator which apparrently has a method inside it that returns value of a compareTo using two objects of type T. So questions:

1. Is this defining a method inside a method? I thought you couldn't do
   that in Java.
2. Is it returning a method? Something I also thought you couldn't do
   in Java.
3. How do I use this? The book uses examples where other, similar,
   methods have parameters.

This has no parameters, so where do o1 and o2 come from?

Comment: Anonymous classes: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: Look closely, o1 and o2 are parameters, thats where they come from.

Comment: I edited your post to use markdown syntax for the enumeration, but I think the last sentence should be at question 3). Apologies!

Answer (score 5):

It is an [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html):

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Comparator<T> reverseOrder() {
    return new Comparator<T>() {
        public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
            return o2.compareTo(o1);
        }
    };
}
```

You are:

1. Declaring a method `compare` in the anonymous class, which is in the method `reverseOrder`.
2. Returning an instance of the anonymous class.
3. Declaring  `o1` and `o2` as the parameters of `compare`.

Answer (score 0):

Questions / Attempted Answers:

> As I follow you have a method using a wildcard that extends comparable where it compares types T and "above."

Methods can extend nothing, so no, this is not correct. The method is generic and can be used with concrete class that extends Comparable.

> It then returns a new Comparator which apparrently has a method inside it that returns value of a compareTo using two objects of type T. So questions:

OK, kind of correct.

> 1) Is this defining a method inside a method? I thought you couldn't do that in Java.

It is not a method in a method. It's a method that returns an **object** of the type Comparator that has its own compare method.

> 2) Is it returning a method? Something I also thought you couldn't do in Java.

No, it returns an object of an anonymous inner class.

> 3) How do I use this? The book uses examples where other, similar, methods have parameters. This has no parameters, so where do o1 and o2 come from?

The o1 and o2 are the declared parameters of the Comparator object's compare method.

Answer (score 0):

Following tutorials about Comparators and Anonymous classes might help:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-use-an-anonymous-class-in-java.html